# Recuperar valores do server-side

Tags: jquery-datatables, lado-do-servidor

Tenho um datatables que me lista os valores da seguinte forma:

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>                                            
      <th>Protocolo</th>
      <th>Assunto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                                    
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var otable = $('#datatable_fixed_column').DataTable({

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "server_processing/protocolos.php",

    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],

    "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "80%", "targets": 1 },
    ],
"sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-6'f><'col-xs-6'<'toolbar'>>r>"+
            "t"+
            "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>"
    });

     $("div.toolbar").html('<div class="text-right"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="SmartAdmin" style="width: 111px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>');

})
```

Eu gostaria de incluir nessa tabela mais uma coluna com um botão para editar, assim:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" id="idcontrib" name="idcontrib" value="<?=$protocolo?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" name="edit_contrib">
      Editar
    </button>
</form>
```

Observe que a variável `$protocolo` armazenaria o valor do protocolo naquela linha.

Como eu faço para atribuir o valor do protocolo a uma variável?

Estou tentando reproduzir algo do tipo:

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>                                            
      <th>Protocolo</th>
      <th>Assunto</th>
      <th>Ação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                                    
</table>

2134    Teste    [Editar] ($protocolo = 2134)
9999    teste 2  [Editar] ($protocolo = 9999)
```

Comment: Galera, continuo sem conseguir, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Galera, vamos lá, alguém pode me ajudar ? será que isso é impossível ??